# Spark strange behaviour: printing list in map over group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Simple case with strange `println` behaviour in Spark `map` function.

Some records are first grouped by `id`. In this case all records have the same `id`, so we get a single group. Then maping over this group we get `RDD[List[Strange.R]]` and next convert it to `List[Strange.R]`. Iterating and printing this list for some reason prints its elements twice. Why?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

object Strange {

  case class R(foo: String, bar: String, id: Int)
  val recs = Array(
    R("foo1", "bar1", 1),
    R("foo2", "bar2", 1),
    R("foo3", "bar3", 1))

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty.server").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    // set up environment
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Test")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rs = sc.parallelize(recs)
    test(rs)
  }

  def test(rs:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[R]) = {
    val grp = rs.groupBy({r=>r.id}) // group records by id
        println("*** Group count: "+grp.count())
    val rddLst = grp.map(tuple => tuple match{ 
      case (id, iter) => {
        val x = iter.toList
        println("--- List size: "+x.size)
        x.foreach(println)
        x
        } 
      })
    val rdd = rddLst.flatMap(identity)
    println("*** RDD[List] count: "+rddLst.count+" RDD count: "+rdd.count)
  }
}
```

And output is:

```
*** Group count: 1
--- List size: 3
R(foo1,bar1,1)
R(foo2,bar2,1)
R(foo3,bar3,1)
--- List size: 3
R(foo1,bar1,1)
R(foo2,bar2,1)
R(foo3,bar3,1)
*** RDD[List] count: 1 RDD count: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that spark RDDs are 'lazily evaluated', so whenever you do an action on an RDD, such as count, it will execute all the transforms (such as map) on that RDD, even if they've been executed before.

So when you run

```
rddLst.count
```

this executes the code within the map (where you're doing println)

and that code is executed again when you do

```
rdd.count
```

You can see how an RDD is composed of by calling rdd.toDebugString.

If you want the transform to run only once, you could put .cache on the result of the map, but this doesn't guarantee it as caching is only a optimisation hint to spark.

To be pedantic, code within map should be side-effect free, and that's why you're seeing 'strange' behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! `cache()` solves this problem. Yet I have never realized that lazy computation in Scala implies excessive computation. Not true for FP in general.

Comment: It'd require computation or storage. And for huge datasets it probably doesn't make sense to store. Remember pure FP won't allow side-effects, so these kind of artifacts wouldn't show up regardless of whether they decide to recompute and cache. Btw lazy val in scala is different, that caches the result after being computed once.

Comment: Instead of `println`, which generates side-effect, it could be some pure function that further transforms data (reducing list for example). In the example we are discussing, reduce would be executed twice. Correct?

Comment: Yes it would. Forgot to say, this is one of the reasons RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset) is resilient, as in, even if the node on which its been computed crashes in the middle of computation, it can recalculate it again given the original data.

Comment: Excessive computation does not always mean resillient distributed data. Sometimes it does and sometimes it just generates unneccessary overhead.  As in the example we are discussing ))

Comment: @AjayPadala More than a year later: so how does one go about mapping the values of an RDD and executing a "side effect" action?